# How to make the delimiter disappear at the end of the line

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

I have a CSV file that I open in Excel. I want to get rid of the last column. I erase it and save the file as CSV but a delimiter is present at the end of line like there is an empty value after.

How can I get rid of it?

I have this:

```
 xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,
```

I want this when saving:

```
 xxx,xxxx,xxxx
```

Comment: Does the column have a heading?

Comment: no it does not have a heading

Comment: My guess would be that for whatever reason excel sees an additional column for that table that is empty. In which case it would do that case of export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with Notepad++ to 'fix' the issue

I am also assuming the issue is due to having a comma at the end of the line.

In Notepad++, open find (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Then choose the radio button for `Extended mode`. Search for

```
,\r\n
```

It should highlight what you want.

To fix it, within the same window, click on the second tab (Replace)

Find:

```
,\r\n
```

Replace with:

```
\r\n
```

[image]

Comment: OK.. I accept this solution but it is too bad that Excel cannot do that or ignore empty columns

Comment: I've not said Excel can't do this - in fact, it can if you want to write VBa to do it for you, but IMO it's easier this way :)